# Cloning an AWS RDS with a snapshot

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, relational-database

I'm trying to create a copy of a existing database in the AWS (RDS) Console with a snapshot of the database however the button for migrating the snapshot is disabled, what might be the reason for that?
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: This is for migrating to Aurora. For this: "The DB snapshot must be from an RDS DB instance running PostgreSQL 9.6.1 or 9.6.3". Thus what is your version?

Comment: The version is 10.10, how can I make a replica now?

Comment: You mean Read Repliac? Or fully separate instance of the db? If the latter, restoring from the snapshot should be sufficient.

Comment: I'd like a fully separate instance of the db, as I remember I already did that with migrating a snapshot, however since a couple of weeks that's not possible anymore

Comment: OH your 100% right restoring is what I would like to do, thank you so much for your help :D

Comment: no problem. I will make awnser based on the comments if you don't mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, the solution to the issue was to use `Restore` option, instead of `Migrate`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to choose the “Copy” option not the migrate.

Comment: That just copys the snapshot however I would like to make a replica of the existing db